# Select rows based on values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I got the following tables in my mysql database: http://i.gyazo.com/8da933221a20ecb0e8f4a8073a2a5b41.png

```
table: ACCOUNTS
ID  NAMN
--  -----
 1  Name1
 2  Name2
 3  Name3
 4  Name4

table: SUBBED
SUBSCRIBER RECEIVER
---------- --------
 1          4
 1          3
```

I would like to select `ID, NAME` from `ACCOUNTS` where account X (lets say the one with ID 1) isn't subscribed to.

If you look at the image, you can see that the account with `NAME = Name1` is subscribed to `Name3` and `Name4`. In this case, the query should return the second row from `ACCOUNTS` where `ID = 2`.

Does someone know what the query might look like?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to `left join` the tables together, and then find the ones that don't match.  Something like this:

```
select a1.* 
  from accounts a1
    left join subbed s1
      on a1.id = s1.receiver
        and s1.subscriber = 1
  where s1.subscriber is null and a1.id <> 1;
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a858f/5)

Comment: We usually refer to this pattern as an "**anti-join**"... an outer join to return all rows from one table, along with matching rows from the other table, and then exclude all rows that had a match. (+1)  e.g. to return rows from `a` with no match in `b`:   **`a LEFT JOIN b ON b.col = a.col WHERE b.col IS NULL`**

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```sql
SELECT ID, NAME FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT RECEIVER FROM SUBBED)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: BEWARE of returning a NULL value in the subquery. If a NULL is returned by the subquery, the result is well defined. But, the uninitiated usually don't expect that result, and isn't the result that they actually wanted. If we don't have a guarantee that `RECEIVER` is not null in `SUBBED`, we need to add a predicate to the subquery... `WHERE RECEIVER IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID, NAME 
From ACCOUNTS
Where ID Not In (Select RECEIVER 
                 From SUBBED 
                 Where SUBSCRIBER = (Your X))
```